# Как изменить ориентацию игры LibGDX на вертикальную?

Tags: java, libgdx

Как изменить ориентацию игры LibGDX на вертикальную?

Comment: Подразумевается андроид платформа? Просто в метках нет метки android, поэтому переспросил.

Answer (score 1):

У вас, по хорошему, для каждой платформы свой подпроект с нужным лаучнером.

Для Android ориентацию менять так:

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

в AndroidManifest.xml добавить android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
после activity

Answer (score 1):

Зайди в файл androidmanifest.xml и пиши 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"